# Javascript, module.exports in chapter 10 of "Eloquent Javascript"

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Here is the code:

```
   function require(name) {
  if (name in require.cache)
    return require.cache[name];

  var code = new Function("exports, module", readFile(name));
  var exports = {}, module = {exports: exports};
  code(exports, module);

  require.cache[name] = module.exports;
  return module.exports;
}
require.cache = Object.create(null);
```

What is the role of this  `require.cache`  object? And why can't `exports`   variable hold a function, for example? Because the author of the book tells us that we can not export a function, for example, into this variable.

As far as I can see, bot `export` and `module.export` will (and actually can) hold the same kind of data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is used to avoid re-requiring something, this is used in the first line of the require, otherwise, you have to actually read the file.

That line:
    var exports = {}, module = {exports: exports};

make it that exports and module.exports refer to the same object.

There is no reason that you couldn't not export a function though, what is the actual wording of the author?

Comment: Here is the quote: ...problem is that it is not possible for a module to directly export a value other than the `exports` object, such as a function. For example, a module might want to export only the constructor of the object type it defines. Right now, it cannot do that because `require` always uses the `exports` object it creates as the exported value.

Comment: The traditional solution for this is to provide modules with another variable, `module`, which is an object that has a property `exports`. This property initially points at the empty object created by `require` but can be overwritten with another value in order to export something else.